# SQL Error when creating a table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, primary-key

I have a problem when I run this SQL query:

```
 CREATE TABLE `softwaredb`.`profile`
    ( `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
     `user_id` INT(11) NOT NULL ,
     `gender` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL , 
    `height` INT(4) NOT NULL ,
     `weight` INT(4) NOT NULL ,
     `bodytype` INT(1) NOT NULL )
```

The error I keep running into is the following:

> Incorrect table definition;
>   there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key

Comment: Try defining the auto increment column as a key ...

Comment: In the future, please add the tag of the specific database software you are using.

Comment: Thanks for the sugestion. I`m using phpmyadmin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
CREATE TABLE `softwaredb`.`profile`
( `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
 `user_id` INT(11) NOT NULL ,
 `gender` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL , 
`height` INT(4) NOT NULL ,
 `weight` INT(4) NOT NULL ,
 `bodytype` INT(1) NOT NULL ,
primary key (id) //specify id as primary key will sort out the error..try
)
```

OR Try

```
CREATE TABLE `softwaredb`.`profile`
    ( `id` INT(11) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT ,
     `user_id` INT(11) NOT NULL ,
     `gender` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL , 
    `height` INT(4) NOT NULL ,
     `weight` INT(4) NOT NULL ,
     `bodytype` INT(1) NOT NULL 
    )
```